# extract a dictionary inside a list

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, flask, scheduler

`[{'_id': ObjectId('6204dda64e780dcc064f5d21'), 'account_name': 'ami', 'debit_account': '33649785257', 'debit_amount': '500', 'con_account_no': '24296548569'}, {'_id': ObjectId('6204de164e780dcc064f5d22'), 'account_name': 'clement', 'debit_account': '33649785257', 'debit_amount': '450000', 'con_account_no': '33389201692'}, {'_id': ObjectId('6204ff2fb401b8ef4aef4542'), 'account_name': 'aka', 'debit_account': '33649785257', 'debit_amount': '400', 'con_account_no': '32206575370'}]`

How do I remove the list above to just dictionary like

`{'_id': ObjectId('6204dda64e780dcc064f5d21'), 'account_name': 'ami', 'debit_account': '33649785257', 'debit_amount': '500', 'con_account_no': '24296548569'}, {'_id': ObjectId('6204de164e780dcc064f5d22'), 'account_name': 'clement', 'debit_account': '33649785257', 'debit_amount': '450000', 'con_account_no': '33389201692'}, {'_id': ObjectId('6204ff2fb401b8ef4aef4542'), 'account_name': 'aka', 'debit_account': '33649785257', 'debit_amount': '400', 'con_account_no': '32206575370'}`

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have more than 1 object inside the list. If you want select one object directly from the list you must specify the object index (starts from 0 to len(list)-1) by adding "[object_index]" beside of list, like that:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('6204dda64e780dcc064f5d21'), 'account_name': 'ami', 'debit_account': '33649785257', 'debit_amount': '500', 'con_account_no': '24296548569'}, {'_id': ObjectId('6204de164e780dcc064f5d22'), 'account_name': 'clement', 'debit_account': '33649785257', 'debit_amount': '450000', 'con_account_no': '33389201692'}, {'_id': ObjectId('6204ff2fb401b8ef4aef4542'), 'account_name': 'aka', 'debit_account': '33649785257', 'debit_amount': '400', 'con_account_no': '32206575370'}][0]
```

This must returns:

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId('6204dda64e780dcc064f5d21'), 
    'account_name': 'ami', 
    'debit_account': '33649785257', 
    'debit_amount': '500', 
    'con_account_no': '24296548569'
}
```

Its a good practice store the objects list into an variable so you can access one object or more specifying theyrs indexes and with this practice you can iterate over the object list.

```
accounts=[
    {'_id': ObjectId('6204dda64e780dcc064f5d21'), 'account_name': 'ami', 'debit_account': '33649785257', 'debit_amount': '500', 'con_account_no': '24296548569'}, 
    {'_id': ObjectId('6204de164e780dcc064f5d22'), 'account_name': 'clement', 'debit_account': '33649785257', 'debit_amount': '450000', 'con_account_no': '33389201692'}, 
    {'_id': ObjectId('6204ff2fb401b8ef4aef4542'), 'account_name': 'aka', 'debit_account': '33649785257', 'debit_amount': '400', 'con_account_no': '32206575370'}
]
firstAccount=accounts[0]
```

Content of firstAccount

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId('6204dda64e780dcc064f5d21'), 
    'account_name': 'ami', 
    'debit_account': '33649785257', 
    'debit_amount': '500', 
    'con_account_no': '24296548569'
}
```

With this pratice you can iterate over the object list.

Note that both methods returns the dict object that corresponds to informed index.

Comment: Is there a way to iterate to get all key and values using a function?

Comment: that can be done with lambda `get_id = lambda objectList: [obj['_id'] for obj in objectList]`
the call for this lambda might be `get_id(pass_here_the_object_ist)` this will retrurn a list with all indexes